Type error: 'MDXRemote' cannot be used as a JSX component
Describe the bug
Failed to build an app next with the command : npm run build
the package.json
{
    "name": "next-app-template",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx -c .eslintrc.json --fix"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nextui-org/avatar": "^2.0.33",
        "@react-aria/ssr": "3.9.4",
        "@react-aria/visually-hidden": "3.8.12",
        "clsx": "2.1.1",
        "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
        "framer-motion": "~11.1.1",
        "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
        "intl-messageformat": "^10.5.0",
        "next": "14.2.4",
        "next-mdx-remote": "^5.0.0",
        "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
        "react": "18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "18.3.1",
        "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0"
    }
}

the page.tsx
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote/rsc";

import { getAllPostIds, getPost } from "@/lib/post";

const components = {
  h2: ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const anchor = `${children.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase()}`;

    return (
      <h2 data-section id={anchor}>
        {children}
      </h2>
    );
  }
};

export default async function BlogPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {
  const post = getPost(params.slug);

  return (
    <div className="max-h-fit">
              <MDXRemote components={components} source={post.content} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const postIds = await getAllPostIds();

  return postIds;
}

the error at build
./app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx:125:16
Type error: 'MDXRemote' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Promise<ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>>' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Promise<ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

There is no problem with the npm run dev
thx
Reproduction
you can try on you self side
next-mdx-remote version
v5.0.0

Add "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ] to the paths in tsconfig.json.
For more doubts, Visit Here

I tried this tsconfig without any different result :
"paths": {
"@/": ["./"],
"react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
}
